# How to use "Always Move Messages in This Conversation" feature from VBA in MS Outlook?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to implement a search and move feature in MS Outlook. Search is OK, it works like charm. But, I can find only the Move function to move message into an Outlook folder.

I use the Always Move Messages in This Conversation feature manually. Now, I'd like to use it from macro. Is there any way to use this feature from VBA?

Here is the current implementation but it uses the simple Move feature:

```
Private Sub btn_Click()
    Dim currentMail As Object
    Dim F As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Msg$
    Set currentMail = Application.ActiveWindow
    If TypeOf currentMail Is Outlook.Inspector Then
      Set currentMail = obj.CurrentItem
    Else
      Set currentMail = obj.Selection(1)
    End If

    currentMail.Move Folder
End Sub
```

Comment: Not the question you asked but this may be useful. Put `Option Explicit` at the top of the module. You could go into the VBE's Tools | Options | Editor and check 'Require Variable Declaration'. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8216322/1571407

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want

```
Dim currentMail As MailItem
Dim conv As Conversation
Dim myFolder As Folder 'you have to set it to your target folder

Set conv = currentMail.GetConversation
conv.SetAlwaysMoveToFolder myFolder, myFolder.Store
```

Comment: Wow, it works perfectly! :) Thank you very much, I've been waiting for it for a year ago. You made me very happy :)

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help!! (That's my first accepted answer!)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what your asking but here is how to move outlook messages in some conversations to sub-folder.

Update `SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("Temp")` Temp folder

Code will search all messages in same conversation in your outlook and then move it to Temp folder

```
Option Explicit
Sub MoveConv()
    Dim olNs As NameSpace
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim SelectedItem As Object
    Dim Item As Outlook.MailItem ' Mail Item
    Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder ' Current Item's Folder
    Dim Conversation As Outlook.Conversation ' Get the conversation
    Dim ItemsTable As Outlook.Table ' Conversation table object
    Dim MailItem As Object

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

'    On Error GoTo MsgErr
'   // Must Selected Item.
    Set SelectedItem = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

'   // If Item = a MailItem.
    If TypeOf SelectedItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        Set Item = SelectedItem
        Set Conversation = Item.GetConversation

        If Not IsNull(Conversation) Then
            Set ItemsTable = Conversation.GetTable

            For Each MailItem In Conversation.GetRootItems ' Items in the conversation.
                If TypeOf MailItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
                    Set Item = MailItem
                    Set Folder = Item.Parent
                    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("Temp") ' Move to Temp Folder
                    Debug.Print Item.ConversationID & " In Folder " & Folder.Name
                    GetConv Item, Conversation
                    Item.Move SubFolder
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If

MsgErr_Exit:
    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing
    Set SelectedItem = Nothing
    Set MailItem = Nothing
    Exit Sub

'// Error information
MsgErr:
    MsgBox "Err." _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
         , vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume MsgErr_Exit
End Sub

Function GetConv(Item As Object, Conversation As Outlook.Conversation)
    Dim Items As Outlook.SimpleItems
    Dim MailItem As Object
    Dim Folder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim olNs As NameSpace
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set Items = Conversation.GetChildren(Item)

    If Items.Count > 0 Then
        For Each MailItem In Items
            If TypeOf MailItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
                Set Item = MailItem
                Set Folder = Item.Parent
                Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("Temp")
                Debug.Print Item.ConversationID & " In Folder " & Folder.Name
                Item.Move SubFolder
            End If
            GetConv Item, Conversation
        Next
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Hi, it's something similar but not exactly what I'm looking for.

If you use the Always Move Messages in This Conversation feature then you have to set the destination folder only once for the first e-mail. The messages in the conversation received later will be placed to the specified folder automatically by the Outlook.

With your solution, I have to identify the destination folder for every new e-mail.

However, I'll change my current implementation to this one because if I have already received more e-mails in the same conversation the this solution is a bit more sophisticated. Thank you!